# Changing Signatures in APK file Android studio

Tags: android, apk, signature

I recently made my first app in Android Studio and made it into an APK. Google play said I had the wrong signature for the APK but I don't know how to change the APK with different signatures nor revert the program back in order to manually change it inside Android Studio. Any help on this?

Here is step by step what I did to get to this point. I finished writing my program and went to "build" then "generate signed apks" where I went through the process of making the keys, key store etc. At this point everything is fine. I just need to somehow go back into the apk and either change the signatures of it or unpack the apk in studio and redo the process of generating signed apks.

Comment: Please give details of the "wrong signature" error message. I suspect it told you more than that.

Comment: This is the error message I received exactly "You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures"

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the apk with the same public-key certificate which you use in the previous uploaded apk. When you build the release apk via `Build -> Generate Signed Apk..`, you will be presented with the following dialog:

[image]

Then you must use the same certificate file (something like `android.jks`) for the `Key store path`.

The documentation says:

> Every app must use the same certificate throughout its lifespan in
>   order for users to be able to install new versions as updates to the
>   app. For more about the benefits of using the same certificate for all
>   your apps throughout their lifespans, see Signing Considerations
>   below.

So, if you lose the certificate file, there is no way you can upload the apk with the same package name again. It will lose forever, gone. You also can't delete the published apk to reuse the same package name again.

Comment: I've already built the release apk, which is the problem. There is no option to click "generate signed apk". I've tried every button under the build tab and nothing is working.

Comment: Strange, what version of Android Studio did you use?

Comment: 3.0.1, i just downloaded android studio last week.

Comment: @adamlawson: I'm using the same version. Check your app `build.gradle`, the certificate file may be declared in it.

Comment: I just checked it and I don't see anything in there about a certificate file